# if message.author.bot: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Hi im building a discord bot and discovered that my commands stopped working after i added the on message event. i read a docs and added `await client.process_commands(msg)` and the error started to pop out. I am quite new to the dicord bot world and i do not understand many things. Please help me.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    channel = message.channel
    with open ("eg.json") as file:
        eg_json = json.load(file)
        file.close()
    egchoices = eg_json["choices"]

    with open ("eg2.json") as file:
        eg2_json = json.load(file)
        file.close()
    eg2choices = eg2_json["choices"]

    with open ("eg3.json") as file:
        eg3_json = json.load(file)
        file.close()
    eg3choices = eg3_json["choices"]

    if msg in egchoices:
        await channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/pGJUyaVEdHQAAAAC/pepe-frog.gif")
    elif msg in eg2choices:
        await channel.send("https://c.tenor.com/UnrUzRgwzncAAAAd/pepe-meme.gif")
    elif msg in eg3choices:
        await channel.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/934284029585395712/934284118341079120/bleach.mp4")

    await client.process_commands(msg)
```

the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 415, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Bitter\VCS\Server Bot\server_bot.py", line 46, in on_message
    await client.process_commands(msg)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1088, in process_commands
    if message.author.bot:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder The relevant parts are posted. As for @Bitter, replace `client.process_commands(msg)` with `client.process_commands(message)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess then, but what about this part: `if message.author.bot:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'`?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs It worked after i moved it on top of  ```msg = message.content```.  Thank you!

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder As per the traceback, that error is in `bot.py`, a library file of nextcord.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, oh, I didn't expect Nextcord to have such code :P (I didn't read this part: `File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1088, in process_commands`)